Grammar of Ephesians 3:14-19 - triple "hina" clauses in Greek?
In Ephesians 3:14-19, a single sentence in Greek, Paul includes three consecutive "hina" clauses at the beginning of verses 16, 18, and the middle of verse 19 - my question is this: are these clauses parallel or do they build off of each other? Are there Greek grammatical rules to determine the answer? Let me give two examples in English of the difference between the two to show precisely what I am asking:

"I am going to work out, so that I will live longer, so that I will look better, and so that I can get healthy." In a sentence like this, each of the "so that" clauses point back to the main verbal clause, and are not dependent or building off of one another. Their order does not really matter - they are parallel.

"I am going to go to the store so that I can buy flour so that I can bake a cake, so that I can celebrate my wife's birthday well." In this sentence, the second "hina" clause subordinates the first, etc. They are subordinated under each other, building off each other.


In the passage at hand, among the first two options, what is Paul doing and how can you tell? Are there Greek grammatical rules to apply to other, similar passages like these beyond mere context? Is there no way to tell other than educated guesses of context? All of the Ephesians commentaries I tried seem silent/apathetic on this matter, as do my Greek Grammar and syntax books. John Piper's "Look at the Book" video claims they are consequential but gives no justification as to why he thinks this is the case.

I think the short answer is, ‘no’.  The syntax won’t help you.  But, all is not hopeless.  In fact, your excellently worded question provides solid hints to a better answer than simply ‘no’.
I suggest the following discourse structure (from the NASB).  It’s still ambiguous relative to your question, but I’ve bolded the verbs to highlight what is called Pragmatics. (see https://www.masterclass.com/articles/pragmatics-in-linguistics-guide for an excellent high level introduction to Pragmatics).  I’ll attempt to clarify the ambiguity.

14 For this reason I bend my knees before the Father,


15 from whom every family in heaven and on earth derives its name,





16 that He would grant you,  according to the riches of His glory, to be
strengthened with power through His Spirit in the inner self, 17 so
that Christ may dwell in your hearts through faith; and that you,
being rooted and grounded in love,


18 [that you] may be able to comprehend  with all the saints what is
the width and length and height and depth, 19 and to know the love of
Christ which surpasses knowledge,




that you may be filled to all the fullness of God.


The question you need to answer in order to answer the question you’ve presented is this:  Do these verbs build on each other, showing elements of logical or temporal consequence, or are the verbs logically parallel?
In order to answer that question, however, one needs to delve into the context.  This is why there’s no simple syntactic answer to your question.  Meaning is conveyed by much more than just syntax.  There’s also Linguistic Semantics and Linguistic Pragmatics.  But,  here I need to clarify what I mean, and what Pragmatics means, by ‘context’.
Context is more than the text around the text.  The article mentioned above gives the example of the syntactic construction: “How are you?”  Is that simply a greeting, or is it a question eliciting a contentful answer, like the joke where the cold caller gets Ms. Smith on the phone and starts with, “Hello!  How are you, Ms. Smith?” to which she immediately replies with, “O!  You have no idea.  Let me tell you all about it.”  That’s not the answer the cold caller was hoping for.
There’s a lot of conventionalized meaning surrounding a text, nearly any text.  We tend to bristle at allowing that meaning to influence, or even guide, our understanding of the Biblical text.  We tend to label it subjective and therefore dismiss it.  The problem with that is God hasn’t designed language or communication to work with no subjective element.  He has forced us into a position where we have to incorporate the objective truth in order to actually own it for ourselves.  Interestingly (from a lexical-linguistic perspective) ‘incorporation’ is like an incarnational state.  It’s like the two natures of objective and subjective have a hypostatic union in order to be relevant in the real-world.  If truth is entirely and only objective, we never benefit from it.  However, it is right and good to keep the sacred and objective text in its authoritative position.
So, we have to allow those verbs to reach out into the surrounding, conventialized, context.  The conventialized nature of meaning provides what is necessary for communication to actually happen.  If we didn’t agree that X means Y, we couldn’t even talk to each other.  This is what linguists talk about when they talk about Pragmatics.  We shouldn’t reject this.  The vast context shouldn’t, however, rule the text since often context must be the thing that changes.  But, we can’t dismiss Pragmatic meaning since it often (far more often than we’re cognizant of) clarifies the authorial intention. Otherwise, Paul’s writings would read like legalese as he would attempt to remove all contextual possibilities and be pedantically explicit.  And 3 John would be 20 pages long and in 6 point font.
Hopefully, that answers the question of why I’m answering the way I’m answering.
First, then, is what’s the main verb and what, in the context, is it referring to?  I completely agree with @dottard in that Paul seems to like long sentences.  The “rambling” sentence is Paul syntactically and semantically massaging the heck out of the meaning he wants to convey.  Here, Paul says he’s praying, and he states the content that (ἵνα) he’s praying about.  I point this out so we know that it’s a context characterized by speaking.  That “speaking thing” provides the framework within which we interpret what is being spoken.  So, immediately, there’s a lot potentially in the context that has been ruled irrelevant. Everything not speaking related is pushed to the side. This is perhaps your only syntactic/semantic clue.  That is, this is a speaking event and the use of ἵνα means the ἵνα-clauses state the content of what is said.  But, is it parallel or sequential (aka. your question)?  Note that “speaking” is done sequentially, though the act of “speaking” is not determinative.  It just hints.
I’d suggest that these  ἵνα-clauses are progressive.  That is, the clausal verbs (that I highlighted above) Pragmatically follow a model (or perhaps better, a paradigm or a script) of

Initialization
Process
Result

In other words, the conventialized, in-the-real-world, contextual references suggest a logical and  consequential set of actions.  I’m basically asking and answering the question, “To what in the real world do these clausal verbs refer and what are the attributes of these real-world objects?” Initialization being that God would grant a powerful strengthening to the Ephesian church.  The Process is their comprehension of the vastness of Christ’s love, and that strengthening is processed through that comprehension and so it should produce the Result of the full expression of who God is.
So, I suggest that the  ἵνα-clauses are sequential, but there’s really no syntactic or even semantic (Linguistic Semantic) elements to leverage.  One can only get the relevant support by leveraging Pragmatic meaning (that is, contextualized meaning).  If you perform a similar analysis on the English examples you provided, I think you’ll see the same sort of Pragmatic meaning comes into play.  You worded the question very well.
I just realized something.  Your question actually relates directly to Paul's prayer.  We all need strengthening for us to comprehend (the text) so that we fully express, as humanly as possible, who God is (Eph 5:1).

Thank you for your helpful answer, brother! well articulated and nuanced, explaining that while grammar cannot help in this instance, context can help determine which case is more likely - I appreciate your time to answer, and God bless you!

First a literal translation of the text of Eph 3:13-19 (BLB)

13: for reason of this I bow my knees to the Father, from whom every
family in the heavens and on earth is named,
16: that He might give you, according to the riches of His glory,
to be strengthened with power by His Spirit in the inner man, [for]
Christ to dwell in your hearts through faith, being rooted and being
founded in love,
18: that you may be fully able, with all the saints, to comprehend
what is the breadth and length and height and depth, and to know the
love of Christ surpassing knowledge,
19b: that you may be filled unto all the fullness of God.

The first thing to observe is that such a sentence is quite typical of Paul's rambling sentences - very long by modern standards.
Second, and this is also typical of Paul, each new part of the long sentence almost always refers back to that which immediately precedes it.  In this case we have:

V16 is the objective for the statement in V15
V18 is the objective for the statement in V17
V19b is the objective for the statement in V19a

In fact, we see much more of this in the longer chain because Paul uses more than just "hina" as a conjunction in this passage:

V13 - Διὸ = "therefore"
V14: χάριν= "for this reason"
V15: ἐξ οὗ = "from whom"
V16: ἵνα = "so that"
V17: [for] "implied by grammar"
V18: ἵνα = "so that"
V19a: τε = "then"
V19b: ἵνα = "so that"

This sort of rambling was common in Biblical Greek where one's thoughts followed on through a long sentence.

Indeed - some helpful thoughts - but back to my original question though: it seems you are claiming the hina clauses (among other connecting words, as your rightly point out) are subordinating to each otber rather than coordinating. If you believe that this is how the “hina” clauses are functioning, subordinating and not coordinating (which is also a viable option in English grammar) WHY do you think this is the case? can you point out a grammatical rule or principle in Greek? what justification do uou have to back up your claim, please?

@ColeMizel - grammatically, it could be either but the semantics (and not the syntax) dictates which is which in such cases.

Sounds like you’re saying it’s a case by case depending on context rather than a hard and fast rule? Interesting - thanks for your comments!
